# css text not showing when responsive for mobile

Tags: css, responsive-design

First image is for desktop view.it is alright , but when i watch the mobile view in browser . the h1 is going up and not showing in screen.

//second image is for mobile view. i hope have explained the problem here.

**html code**

```
<div class="container" id="slide">

      <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
            <img src="img/bg3.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%; max-height: 900px;">

            <div class="carousel-caption">
            <img src="img/logo1.png" width="50px;" height="50px;">

            <h1 style="font-size: 75px; font-weight: bold; color: #fc4128; text-shadow: 2px 2px #00a0c6; padding-bottom: auto; ">Bluebay Systems Ltd</h1>


          <h3 style="color:white; font-weight: bold;padding-bottom: 50px;">Complete IT Solution For Your Every Need</h3>
          <br>
          <br>
            <a href="#about" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg">Find Out More</a>
        </div>
          </div>

          <div class="item" style=" max-height: 900px;">
            <img src="img/bg1.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%; max-height: 900px;">
             <div class="carousel-caption">
             <img src="img/logo1.png" width="50px;" height="50px;">

            <h1 style="font-size: 75px; font-weight: bold; color: #fc4128; text-shadow: 2px 2px #00a0c6; padding-bottom:auto; ">Bluebay Systems Ltd</h1>

          <h3 style="color: white; font-weight: bold;padding-bottom: 50px;" >Complete IT Solution For Your Every Need</h3>
          <br>
            <a href="#about" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg">Find Out More</a>
        </div>
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <img src="img/bg.jpg" alt="New york" style="width:100%; max-height: 900px;">
             <div class="carousel-caption">
             <img src="img/logo1.png" width="50px;" height="50px;">

            <h1 style="font-size: 75px; font-weight: bold; color: #fc4128; text-shadow: 2px 2px #00a0c6; padding-bottom: auto; ">Bluebay Systems Ltd</h1>

          <h3 style="color: white; font-weight: bold; padding-bottom: 50px;padding-top: 10px;" >Complete IT Solution For Your Every Need</h3>
          <br>
            <a href="#about" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg">Find Out More</a>
        </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**css code**

```
#slide{

    width: 100%;

    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
}
```

[image: this is for full screen]

[image: this is mobile view]

Comment: Could you post your CSS code too, please?

Comment: @AurelBílý  added

Answer (score 0):

Please check Bootstrap css and find the following.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {

  /* Hide captions class  */
  .carousel-caption {
     display: none
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add on bottom of last CSS file, or in media.css for CSS queries:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 767px){


  /* Hide captions class  */
  .carousel-caption {
     display: block !important;
  }
}
```